# Download files from different domains with one connection

Tags: android, network-programming, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

Well this question may sounds a little crazy but I just want to save time and engergy. To open a connection needs time and engergy on a mobile device so I want to reuse open connections if possible.

It can happen that I'll need to download files from `example.com` and `example.net`. Both sites are hosted on the same server/ip so it should be possible to get documents from both documents with just one connection.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://example.com/robots.txt");
HttpGet get2 = new HttpGet("http://example.net/robots.txt");
URI uri = get.getURI();
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getScheme());
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(host, get);
String data = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
Log.v("test", "Downloaded " + data.length() + " bytes from " + get.getURI().toASCIIString());
response = client.execute(host, get2);
data = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
Log.v("test", "Downloaded " + data.length() + " bytes from " + get2.getURI().toASCIIString());
```

The problem is when I don't use that `HttpHost` for each call is a new connection established. If I use that both `Host` HTTP headers points to the first domain. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quiet simple (if you found it):

```
HttpGet get2 = new HttpGet("http://example.com/robots.txt");
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(ClientPNames.VIRTUAL_HOST, new HttpHost("example.net", -1, "http"));
get2.setParams(params);
```

So will the connection be reused because it's the same domain/port/schema and the `DefaultHttpClient` will look for that parameter `ClientPNames.VIRTUAL_HOST`.

I found the solution with the sourcecode which is actuall used by android which is to find on [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/src/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector.java?repo=platform--external--apache-http&name=ics-mr1-release#387).