# EOF Exception in HTTPRequest (Android 4.1)

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I'm (sometimes) encountering a EOFException when making a HTTPRequest. I've already tried to set keepalive ="false" but that didnt help so I guess the Problem must be somewhere else..(Ive got the INTERNET permission)... could it be a problem that this AsyncTask could sometimes be be running more than one time simultaneously?) the code im using is

```
package jo.z.invg.fahrplan;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.http.cookie.ClientCookie;
import org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException;
import org.apache.http.cookie.SetCookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicExpiresHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BrowserCompatSpec;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<PostParam, Void, String> {
    //private Exception exception;
    class LenientCookieSpec extends BrowserCompatSpec {
        public LenientCookieSpec() {
            super();
            registerAttribHandler(ClientCookie.EXPIRES_ATTR, new BasicExpiresHandler(DATE_PATTERNS) {
                @Override public void parse(SetCookie cookie, String value) throws MalformedCookieException {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                        // You should set whatever you want in cookie
                        cookie.setExpiryDate(null);
                    } else {
                        super.parse(cookie, value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private boolean succ = true;
    private int info;
    private int reqnr;
    private ScheduleRequest sreq;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(PostParam...postData) {
        //build the string to store the response text from the server
        Log.d("Test", "Anfrage gesendet");
        String response= "***";

        reqnr = postData[0].reqnr;
        sreq = postData[0].req;
                info = postData[0].in;
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                //do this wherever you are wanting to POST
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection conn;

                try{
                //if you are using https, make sure to import java.net.HttpsURLConnection
                url=new URL(postData[0].adress);

                //you need to encode ONLY the values of the parameters


                String param = EncodeParam(postData[0].postparam);

                conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                //set the output to true, indicating you are outputting(uploading) POST data

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                //once you set the output to true, you don't really need to set the request method to post, but I'm doing it anyway
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                //Android documentation suggested that you set the length of the data you are sending to the server, BUT
                // do NOT specify this length in the header by using conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", length);
                //use this instead.
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                //conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120830 Firefox/15.0");//User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120830 Firefox/15.0

                //send the POST out
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                out.print(param);

                out.close();


                //start listening to the stream
                Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

                //process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
                while(inStream.hasNextLine()){
                response+=(inStream.nextLine());}
                //Log.d("HTTPRequest",response);

                conn.disconnect();

                }

                //catch some error
                catch(MalformedURLException ex){  
                //Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, ex.toString(), 1 ).show();
                    Log.d("HTTPRequest", "Problem beim Postrequest",ex);
                }
                // and some more
                catch(IOException ex){
                    succ = false;
                    if(!(INVG_Fahrplan.INVG_this.isOnline())){INVG_Fahrplan.INVG_this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(INVG_Fahrplan.INVG_this,"Keine Internetverbindung", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });}
                    else{
                        INVG_Fahrplan.INVG_this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(INVG_Fahrplan.INVG_this,"Fehler bei der Abfrage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    Log.d("HTTPRequest", "Problem beim Postrequest",ex);
                //Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, ex.toString(), 1 ).show();
                }
                return response;
            }
    public String EncodeParam (List<PostNameValuePair> para){
        String param = "";
        for (PostNameValuePair nvp: para){
            try{
                param += nvp.name +"=" + URLEncoder.encode(nvp.value, "UTF-8") + "&";
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("HTTPRequest", "Problem beim Postrequest",e);
            }

        }
        return param.substring(0, param.length()-1);
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       if(succ){
        if (info == 1){
        sreq.ParseRequest(result,1,-1,reqnr);
       }else if (info == 2){
           sreq.ParseDetails(result,reqnr);
       }}else{
           sreq.reqerror(info);
       }
        //sreq.ParseRequest(result,1);
    }


 }
```

thanks for help in advance;D

Comment: Maybe your connection breaks. Btw IMHO it is better to do multiple requests with one connection.

Comment: how could i know whether my connection breaks (wifi or a emulator device) ... and how could i do these multiple requests(as i dont know if there will be a second one)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to detect a broken connection, because I had no such situation yet. About the multiple download see also this question: [Download files from different domains with one connection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13287953/995926)

Comment: could you tell me how i can implement that in my code? or is my way of downloading even the correct one (or can i do that better / easier / safer) ??

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error sometimes but only on the emulator - seems like an emulator bug to me.

[How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access) helped me a lot. :)